# Как практически проверить статистическую гипотезу?

Tags: математика, статистика

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно проверить статистическую гипотезу:

**Гипотеза:** "если между двумя обращениями одного клиента прошло менее 10 дней, то наиболее вероятно, что эти обращения связаны одной тематикой".

**Альтернативная гипотеза:** "если между двумя обращениями одного клиента прошло более 10 дней, то наиболее вероятно, что эти обращения связаны одной тематикой

У меня в БД есть записи обращений от разных клиентов.

Я попробовал найти "группы" связанных обращений в компанию, для этого я написал скрипт на python, который находит эти "группы", если от текущего обращения по аккаунту есть другое с шагом t (проверка выполняется пока обращения не будут найдены в нужном шаге)

Для того, чтобы определить шаг t, который с наибольшей вероятностью покажет мне что эти обращения связаны, я построил плотность распределения временных интервалов между текущим обращением и последующим.

Получилось как-то так: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но как математически определить какой временной интервал мне следует взять?

Comment: Уточните свой вопрос. Дело в том, что что-бы проверить статистическую гипотезу ее надо сначала сформулировать и сформулировать альтернативную ей гипотезу. "как математически определить какой временной интервал"  - это никак не гипотеза. Так что-же вам на самом деле надо?

Comment: Гипотеза: "если между двумя обращениями одного клиента прошло менее 10 дней, то наиболее вероятно, что эти обращения связаны одной тематикой".   
 Альтернативная гипотеза:  "если между двумя обращениями одного клиента прошло более 10 дней, то наиболее вероятно, что эти обращения связаны одной тематикой"

Comment: Без формализации критерия "связаны одной темой", не оботись. Синхронные запросы могут вызваны косвенными причинами. Нпример, сотрудник вернулся из отпуска, и решил, с новыми силами, "разгрести завалы давно откладывавшихся дел". Считать ли такие запросы связанными? Т.е. кроме временного ряда нужны еще какие-то данные. Например, можно вручную сгруппировать некоторые запросы, и проверть гипотизу на небольшой подвыборке.

Comment: У вас альтернативная гипотеза неправильная)

Comment: @Chorkov, насколько я понимаю, для больших массивов данных подобные частные случаи не существенны и я могу ими пренебречь. 

У меня есть звонки, уникальный идентификатор клиента и дата время поступившего звонка.

Я строю предположение, что если мне от 1 клиента поступило 2 звонка с интервалом в 1 день - скорее всего они связаны одной причиной обращения. 
Если один и тот же клиент позвонил мне спустя месяц, то более вероятно, что он обратился уже с другим вопросом. Просто хочу эту гипотезу подтвердить математически.

Comment: @pavel подскажите пожалуйста почему?

Comment: @Александр, если критерием "связанности" звонков является интервал между ними, то звонки поступившие с инетрвалом меньше заданного - связаны. По определению. (Тут проверять нечего.) Дайте другое опредленеие связанности, тогда будет предмет для проверки. Если данных для проверки альтернативного определения недостаточно - то ничего нельзя сделать, и нужно искать источник дополнительных данных.

Comment: @Александр "Если один и тот же клиент позвонил мне спустя месяц, то более вероятно, что он обратился уже с другим вопросом"  -  а если спустя две недели или 18 дней? Для проверки/отвержения гипотезы вам необходимо иметь тестовую выборку (чем больше  тем лучше), где для каждого звонка будет информация о том, связан он с предыдущим или нет.  Ведь и для периода в 2 месяца  может быть связь. Вот тогда для каждого периода можно действительно строить модель, которая для БУДУЩИХ звонков будет "предполагать", связан он с предыдущей или нет. У вас есть указанная выборка, что бы проводить анализ дальше?